# Deploy web service programmatically on tomcat

Tags: java, apache, web-services, tomcat, jax-rs

I'm trying to make a service that would deploy WAR file on tomcat server. The class takes input as the path of WAR file and automatically deploys it to the tomcat server once this class in run following is the code. kindly help me with this. also I don't want to use SFTP to upload the WAR while but instead use put request to deploy the WAR file on tomcat. I have seen examples of using FTP or SFTP for the same but that is what I don't require. My service would already be hosted on tomcat, it would auto host the WAR file supplied to it.

```
public class DeployManager {

static CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();;

public static void main(String args[]) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    /*
     * warning only ever AuthScope.ANY while debugging with these settings
     * the tomcat username and pw are added to EVERY request
     */

    credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials("tomcat", "s3cret"));
    deploy();
    // undeploy();
}

private static void deploy() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=C:/Users/Jainesh_Trivedi/Desktop/WAR/AutohostDemo1_1145.war";
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Jainesh_Trivedi\\Desktop\\WAR\\AutohostDemo1_1145.war");

    HttpPut req = new HttpPut(url);
    MultipartEntityBuilder meb = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    meb.addTextBody("Sample", "C:\\Users\\Jainesh_Trivedi\\Desktop\\WAR\\AutohostDemo1_1145.war");

    // "application/octect-stream"
    meb.addBinaryBody("attachment", file, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, file.getName());

    req.setEntity(meb.build());
    String response = executeRequest(req, credsProvider);

    System.out.println("Response : " + response);
}

public static void undeploy() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/manager/text/undeploy?path=/deployMe";
    HttpGet req = new HttpGet(url);
    String response = executeRequest(req, credsProvider);
    System.out.println("Response : " + response);
}

private static String executeRequest(HttpRequestBase requestBase, CredentialsProvider credsProvider)
        throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();
    InputStream responseStream = null;
    String res = null;
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(requestBase);
    HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
    responseStream = responseEntity.getContent();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseStream));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
    br.close();
    res = sb.toString();

    return res;
}
}
```

Error is :

```
    INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
Nov 24, 2015 10:39:23 AM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.streamWrite(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:117)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.flushBuffer(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:129)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.write(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:158)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:114)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody.writeTo(FileBody.java:120)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.AbstractMultipartForm.doWriteTo(AbstractMultipartForm.java:150)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.AbstractMultipartForm.writeTo(AbstractMultipartForm.java:173)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity.writeTo(MultipartFormEntity.java:97)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.invoke(CPoolProxy.java:138)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.sendRequestEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:177)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:77)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:95)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at com.autohost.java.DeployManager.executeRequest(DeployManager.java:68)
    at com.autohost.java.DeployManager.deploy(DeployManager.java:51)
    at com.autohost.java.DeployManager.main(DeployManager.java:35)
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly your question you are trying to reinvent the [tomcat manager](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html)

Comment: yes kind of @user2560528 , my service would take input as the path of the WAR file and host it on the server